# Magento How to show cart information on mouse over on My Cart Link

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to show cart information when user take their mouse over My Cart link on Header. is there any way to show this things.

so it's make easy to user to check their cart detail.if yes then how can it be!

Waiting for your kind response.

Comment: You can refer to the mini-cart in [the official EE demo](http://enterprise-demo.magentocommerce.com/).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by adding a `checkout/cart_sidebar` block to your header in your layout xml. You probably also want to create a separate template for this block based on `checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml`.

Then you can use jQuery to show/hide the content of the cart when a user hovers over the My Cart link.